# Decompositions of acceleration in |F|=m|a|

Tags: multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics

Here is a screenshot of the problem.

[image]

In short it want's you to decompose a in |F| = m|a| but I am still really confused about how to approach this problem.

I know a = v'*T + kv^2*N

Where v' = dv/dt, T = tangent vector, k = kappa/curvature, N = normal vector, v = magnitude of velocity.

But in this problem neither v', T, or N are given????

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since $ \ \kappa \ $ is the _reciprocal_ of the radius of curvature, you can eliminate three choices immediately by dimensional analysis.  The remaining question is whether the factor of $ \ \frac12 \ $ should be there or not...

Comment: Im a little confused with what that means, the radius of curvature is 1/k so k is the reciprocal of 1/k? Also how does this fact help eliminate 3 choices?

Comment: The radius of curvature is the radius of the imaginary (osculating) circle tangent to a point on the curve with the same curvature as the curve there.  So $ \ \kappa \ = \ \frac{1}{r} \ $

Comment: Yes because r = 1/k? but more importantly how does this eliminate 3 answers?

Comment: Look at the exponents on the mass and velocity factors:  which expressions give units of force if $ \ \kappa \ $ has units of inverse length?

Comment: What @boojum is saying is that the dimensions of $F$ are $MLT^{-2}$, i.e. mass times length divided by time squared. Anything that doesn't match those dimensions *cannot* be a correct answer - for example, answer e has dimensions of $M(L/T)(1/L) = MT^{-1}$.

Comment: Another question to ask is: does a tangentially-acting force affect the _direction_ of motion of a "particle"?  That might help you settle on one choice. (Using $ \ \kappa  = \frac{1}{r} \ , $ do any of the choices look like a force expression you've seen before?)